# Fullcalendar with events out of json and one extra (background) event

Tags: php, json, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm working with the fullcalendar.io (version 5) at the moment and I'm creating a tool that helps my team to create customer appointments. It all works fine, but I'm triing to go the extra mile and now I'm struggeling in a detail. Maybe somebody here can help.

When a employee is creating a new customer appoinment, I thougt it would be comfortable to show a small preview calendar of just the day, to doublecheck that the start and end time of the new appointment doesn't overlap with another customers appointment.
So I create a calendar on the website, only showing the selected day and I'm using "events : [ ... ] " to open the json with the appointments that are already inside the calendar.
Works fine.

But I can't figure out how to add the new appointment (that has not yet been saved to the database) as a preview.

This is the calendar script:

```
<script>

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var srcCalendarEl = document.getElementById('source-calendar');
    var srcCalendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(srcCalendarEl, {
        headerToolbar: {
            left: '',
            center: 'title',
            right: ''
        },
        editable: false,
        resizable: false,
        dragRevertDuration: 0,
        allDayText: 'Ganztägig',
        axisFormat: 'H:mm',
        navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
        eventLimit: false, // allow "more" link when too many events
        locale: 'de',
        firstDay: 1,
        initialView: 'timeGridDay',
        allDaySlot: false,
        slotMinTime: '07:00:00',
        slotMaxTime: '20:00:00',
        slotDuration: '00:30:00',   
        contentHeight:"auto",
        droppable: false,
        events: 'events.php?calendar=<?php echo $employeeID; ?>'
    });
    srcCalendar.render();
  });
```

I can easily add the preview appointment like that:

```
        events: [
                    {
                      start: '2022-08-03T10:00:00',
                      end: '2022-08-03T16:00:00',
                      display: 'background'
                    }
                  ]
```

But in that case only my preview appointment is visible, not the entries that are already in the database :(

Is there a way of combaining the JSON entries with my preview entrie to make it easy for the team to figure out if the appointment is possible?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-addEvent will add an event to the calendar

Comment: Or you can specify multiple sources of events - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventSources

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's absolutely correct, I don't know why I wasn't able to find it by myself!